# Does C# have zero-cost abstractions?

Tags: c#, optimization, compiler-optimization, jit

I normally program in languages that have the concept of zero-cost abstractions like C++ and Rust.

Currently I'm working in a project that uses C# language. So I was wondering if I can safely create abstractions and higher level code without compromising the performance.

Is that possible in C# or for performance critical code I should just do as low level code as possible?

Just as an example I encountered in my code (don't focus too much on this example, my question is more high level), I needed a function that would return multiple values, for that, my first approach was to use a tuple, so something like this:

```
public (int, int, float) Function();
```

or Abstract this tuple into a struct:

```
public struct Abstraction { int value1; int value2; float value3; };

public Abstraction Function();
```

What I expected is that the compiler would optimize the `Tuple` or the `Abstraction struct` away and simply use the primitive values directly. But what I found is that writing the code using `out` parameters would improve performance:

```
public void Function(out int value1, out int value2, out float value3);
```

I'm guessing the reason is because in the `out` function, there is no `Tuple` or `Abstraction struct` creation.

The problem with the `out` function version is that I really hate to use parameters as return values, since it seems more like a *hack* to a language limitation.

So, in the end I'm not sure if I'm just not using the correct configuration so the JIT could use zero-cost abstraction or this is simply not possible or not guaranteed in C#.

Comment: This seems like micro-optimization. Any performance cost to using one approach over another is likely to be negligible, and probably irrelevant compared to the overall performance of your algorithms themselves.

Comment: A struct is an abstraction all by itself.  If the method cannot be inlined then the jitter will rewrite the method as void Function(out Abstraction retval).  Just like a C or C++ compiler has to do it.  There are lots of bad benchmark tests out there, this is very fast code and hard to measure.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I don't think it makes sense to say that languages "have zero-cost abstractions". Consider the abstraction of function. Is it zero-cost? Generally speaking, it is zero-cost only if it's inlined. And while C++ compilers tend to be really good about inlining functions, they don't inline all functions, so function in C++ is strictly speaking not a zero-cost abstraction. But this difference only matters rarely in practice, which is why you can usually consider a function to be zero-cost.

Now, modern C++ and Rust are designed and implemented in such a way that they make abstractions zero-cost as often as possible. Is this different in C#? Kind of. C# is not designed with such focus on zero-cost abstractions (e.g. invoking a lambda in C# always involves what's effectively a virtual call; invoking a lambda in C++ does not, which makes it much easier to make it zero-cost). Also, JIT compilers generally can't afford to spend as much time on optimizations like inlining and so they generate worse code for abstractions than C++ compilers. (Though this might change in the future, since [.Net Core 2.1 introduced a tiered JIT](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/08/02/tiered-compilation-preview-in-net-core-2-1/), which means it has more time for optimizations.)

On the other hand, the JIT compiler is tweaked to work well for real code, not for microbenchmarks (which I assume is how you came to the conclusion that returning a `struct` has worse performance).

In my microbenchmark, using a `struct` indeed had worse performance, but it was because JIT decided not to inline that version of `Function`, it was not because of the cost of creating a `struct`, or anything like that. If I fixed that by using `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]`, both versions achieved the same performance.

So, returning a `struct` *can be a zero-cost abstraction in C#*. Though it's true that there is smaller chance of that happening in C# than in C++.

If you want to know what is the actual effect of switching between `out` parameters and returning a `struct`, I suggest you write a more realistic benchmark, not a microbenchmark, and see what the results are. (Assuming I got it right that you used a microbenchmark.)

Comment: Just today I saw somebody use a popular benchmark tool that guaranteed that a micro-benchmarked small method could never be inlined.  Phantom numbers.  Getting to the bottom of the can still requires grokking machine code and optimizers, C# has more can.  That "tiered JIT" comment could use a link btw.

Comment: I get where svick is coming from thinking zero-cost abstractions are inline, but that technically isn't the ideal way to think about it.  A zero-cost abstraction is an abstraction that is as fast as if the abstraction did not exist, inlined or otherwise.

So, for example, if I create a new data type, is it going to be as fast as if it was native allowing the data type to be treated as if it was natively part of the language? (zero-cost) or is this new data type going to be slower than native?

For more explanation see: https://boats.gitlab.io/blog/post/zero-cost-abstractions/

Comment: @Danielle When I mentioned inlining, I was specifically talking about functions. Other abstractions, including custom data types, have different costs, so making them zero-cost indeed might require different techniques.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you "can"; but is very difficult to control. So, you always had to test and measure.

#### A practical example with "zero cost abstraction":

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class App
{
    interface IMessages {
        string Welcome{ get; }
        string Goodbye { get; }
    }       

    partial struct EnglishMessages : IMessages {        
        public string Welcome {
            get { return "Welcome"; }
        }

        public string Goodbye {
            get { return "Goodbye"; }
        }
    }

    partial struct SpanishMessages : IMessages {        
        public string Welcome {
            get { return "Bienvenido"; }
        }

        public string Goodbye {
            get { return "Adios"; }
        }
    }

    static partial class Messages
    {
        public static SpanishMessages BuildLang {
            get { return default; }
        }
    }

    public static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine(Messages.Welcome);
        Console.WriteLine(Messages.Goodbye);
    }

    static partial class Messages
    {   
        public static string Welcome {
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
            get { return GetWelcomeFrom(BuildLang); }
        }

        public static string Goodbye {
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
            get { return GetGoodbyeFrom(BuildLang); }
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static string GetWelcomeFrom<T>()
            where T : struct, IMessages
        {
           var v = default(T);
           return v.Welcome;
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static string GetWelcomeFrom<T>(T _)
            where T : struct, IMessages
        {
            return GetWelcomeFrom<T>();
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static string GetGoodbyeFrom<T>()
            where T : struct, IMessages
        {
           var v = default(T);
           return v.Goodbye;
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static string GetGoodbyeFrom<T>(T _)
            where T : struct, IMessages
        {
            return GetGoodbyeFrom<T>();
        }

    }

#region
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 0)]
    partial struct EnglishMessages { [FieldOffset(0)] int _;  }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 0)]
    partial struct SpanishMessages { [FieldOffset(0)] int _;  }
#endregion
}
```

#### You can able to understand the tricks with this code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class App
{
    interface IMessage {
        string Value { get; }
        bool IsError { get; }
    }   

    static class Messages
    {
        // AggressiveInlining increase the inline cost threshold,
        // decreased by the use of generics.
        //
        // This allow inlining because has low cost,
        // calculated with the used operations.
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static string GetValue<T>()
            where T : struct, IMessage
        {
           // Problem:
           //  return default(T).Value
           //
           // Creates a temporal variable using the CIL stack operations.
           // Which avoid some optimizers (like coreclr) to eliminate them.

           // Solution:
           // Create a variable which is eliminated by the optimizer
           // because is unnecessary memory.
           var v = default(T);
           return v.Value;
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static bool IsError<T>()
            where T : struct, IMessage
        {
           var v = default(T);
           return v.IsError;
        }
    }

    // The use of partial is only to increase the legibility,
    // moving the tricks to the end
    partial struct WelcomeMessageEnglish : IMessage {        
        public string Value {
            get { return "Welcome"; }
        }

        public bool IsError {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }

    partial struct WelcomeMessageSpanish : IMessage {        
        public string Value {
            get { return "Bienvenido"; }
        }

        public bool IsError {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }


    public static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine(Messages.GetValue<WelcomeMessageEnglish>() );
        Console.WriteLine(Messages.GetValue<WelcomeMessageSpanish>() );
    }

// An struct has Size = 1 and is initializated to 0
// This avoid that, setting Size = 0
#region
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 0)]
    partial struct WelcomeMessageEnglish { [FieldOffset(0)] int _;  }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 0)]
    partial struct WelcomeMessageSpanish { [FieldOffset(0)] int _;  }
#endregion
}
```

I "tested" this in CoreClr, Roslyn, Mono and the abstraction has "zero cost":

```
App.Main()
    L0000: push ebp
    L0001: mov ebp, esp
    L0003: mov ecx, [0xfd175c4]
    L0009: call System.Console.WriteLine(System.String)
    L000e: mov ecx, [0xfd17628]
    L0014: call System.Console.WriteLine(System.String)
    L0019: pop ebp
    L001a: ret
```

For coreclr and roslyn, you can view the asm in SharpLab: [Here](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=).

And for mono (in GNU/Linux):

`mono --aot zerocost.exe`

`objdump -d -M intel zerocost.exe.so > zerocost.exe.so.dump`

`cat zerocost.exe.so.dump #Looking for <App_Main>`

Comment: Why do you have a field of type integer in your `WelcomeMessageEnglish` struct? The size of that struct would by four bytes, not the desired zero bytes. What's wrong about an empty struct?

Answer (score 2):

When you return something, you always create a new object – you save that step completely when just working "in place" with your `out` parameters.

Then, you have things that your compiler can't simply optimize away – I'd have to tell you a bit about strict aliasing rules in C, but I don't know C# enough to know whether similar things apply here.

So, in general, creating an object of tuple or `Abstraction` type is not optimizable away. You specifically specified you wanted to return an object of that type, so that object has to be created by a "general" compilation of the function. You could argue that the compiler knows the context in which `Function` is called and could infer that it's OK to not generate the object but directly work as if these were reference to the things that you assign the fields of `Abstraction` to later, but here aliasing rules might get really complicated, and that will in general be logically impossible to do.